# json_encode and json_decode in mySql misunderstanding

Tags: php, mysql, json

I am stuck in my PHP page for a `json_encode` since a couple of days after having done 9999 tests.

The goal is to log on a swift app using mySql database.

So I guess i have something wrong in my query, and i dont know how to send answer of found/not found user in `json_encode()`.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);

// i get the email and password sent as parameter
// my swift code is working, and the next line is ok.
$logs[] = array('email' => $obj->email, 'pass' => $obj->pass);

//echo json_encode($logs); // to send back my logs (ok)

// Create connection
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx");

// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

//echo json_encode($logs);
// its working until here if i execute the previous line and put the rest in comment 

// from the next line its making errors such : 
// Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "JSON text did not start with array or object and option to allow fragments not set." 
$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = '".$logs['email']."'";

//echo json_encode($logs); //not working at this place if i put the rest in comment.

// Check if there are results
if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
    // If so, then create a results array and a temporary one
    // to hold the data
    $resultArray = array();
    $tempArray = array();

    // Loop through each row in the result set
    while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {
        // Add each row into our results array
        $tempArray = $row;
        array_push($resultArray, $tempArray);
    }

    //check the corresponding password
    if ( $logs['pass'] == $resultArray[4]) {
        // i m not sure how to send the answer as a json
        echo json_encode(true);

    } else {
        echo json_encode(false);
    }

}

// Close connections
mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

If I try in php without all json stuff, its working since I put 
`$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = 'ben@test.be'";`
as a test.

The following code works:

```
<?php
$json = file_get_contents('php://input');
$obj = json_decode($json);
$logs[] = array('email' => $obj->email, 'pass' => $obj->pass);

$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "xx", "xx", "xx");

if (mysqli_connect_errno())
{
echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";

if ($result = mysqli_query($con, $sql))
{
$emparray = array();
while($row =mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
    $emparray[] = $row;
}
echo json_encode($emparray);
}

mysqli_close($con);

?>
```

But if I put `$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE email = '$logs['email']'";` instead of `$sql = "SELECT * FROM clients";`
Its not working anymore. It doesn't like my conditional query. What did I misunderstood?

Comment: You're currently creating a multidimensional array. Change `$logs[] = array(...);` to `$logs = array(...);`. If you do it as you currently are, you would need to get the email with `$logs[0]['email']`.

Comment: You are wide open to [SQL Injections](http://php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php) and should really use [Prepared Statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) instead of concatenating your queries. Specially since you're not escaping the user inputs at all! It's not only for security reasons, since if any of your inputs contains `'` or ends with a backslash, your query will currently fail. Concatenating queries are bad for many reasons.

Comment: just check for the password in the `while($row = $result->fetch_object()) {` & if success then do `echo json_encode($row);` Also change the `$logs[]` to `$logs`

Comment: thanks guys, indeed it was a problem from the logs array.